# Using Gsub to capture the first letter after a colon : and transform it into uppercase

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I need to capture the first letter after the colon : and transform it into uppercase. My input is:

```
ID1423:Bellatorias obiri           18 Aug 2006
ID2533:Caretta caretta             16 Jul 2000
ID342:Cyclodomorphus praealtus     24 Dec 2009
ID8777:Dermochelys coriacea         8 Jan 2009
ID922:Egernia stokesii badia       16 Jul 2000
```

The code I am using is reptiledata <- gsub("(\w)(\w+)", ":\U\1", reptile_data, perl = TRUE)

and I am getting an output like this:

```
> reptiledata
[1] "c(:1, :1, :2, 8, :1, :1, :1, :1, :1, :1, :1, :2, 4, :1, :1, :1)"  
[2] "c(2, 6, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 1, 2, 6, 6)"                

etc...
```

I need a generic gsub code that will transform many first letter characters after the colon into uppercase and not just the ones shown. Thanks for any help!

Comment: @tripleee It is R, let me edit the tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `gsub` in Perl mode with the uppercase replacement modififier `\U`:

```
gsub(":([A-Za-z])", ":\\U\\1", str, perl=TRUE)
```

This will replace any colon followed by a single letter with a colon followed by the uppercase version of that letter.  We could make this pattern more specific if you find it firing on text which should not be modified.

### Demo

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help. When I input >reptiledata<-gsub(":([A-Za-z])", ":\\U\\1", reptile_data, str, TRUE) I get this output reptiledata
[1] "c(18, 16, 24, 8, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 23, 4, 18, 16, 16)"                                  
[2] "c(2, 6, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 1, 2, 6, 6)"                                                
[3] "c(2006, 2000, 2009, 2009, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2011, 2001, 2006, 2000, 2000)"

Comment: @KiwiPower No...the flag is `perl=TRUE`.

Comment: reptiledata<-gsub(":([A-Za-z])", ":\\U\\1", reptile_data, perl=TRUE), I am still getting a numerical output of reptiledata
[1] "c(18, 16, 24, 8, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 23, 4, 18, 16, 16)"                                  
[2] "c(2, 6, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 1, 2, 6, 6)"                                                
[3] "c(2006, 2000, 2009, 2009, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2011, 2001, 2006, 2000, 2000)".

Comment: Then your data has a problem, or it is something other than what you showed us.  See if you can edit my demo with other data and get it to break.  Then paste the link here and I can have a look at it.

Comment: reptile_data <- read.table("https://wurmlab.github.io/teaching/2013sbc361/reptile_data.txt", row.names = 1)    stackoverflow is taking out the https:// which is needed to connect to the website for dataset.

Comment: Your links are broken, and that is not what I asked for.  Give me a small reproducible example where my answer fails, or if not then change your question to the actual requirement.

Comment: well my dataset uploads into R and displays the relevant information. >Reptile_data  V2  V3   V4
ID1423:Bellatorias obiri           18 Aug 2006
ID2533:Caretta caretta             16 Jul 2000
ID342:Cyclodomorphus praealtus     24 Dec 2009
When using reptile<-gsub(":([A-Za-z])", ":\\U\\1", reptile_data, perl=TRUE) I receive the following output > reptile
[1] "c(18, 16, 24, 8, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 23, 4, 18, 16, 16)"                                  
[2] "c(2, 6, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 1, 2, 6, 6)" and so on,possible dataset issue

Comment: if you are able to use the link I uploaded however include (https:// infront of wurmlab.github.io/teaching/2013sbc361/reptile_da‌​ta.txt";, row.names = 1) then the link will work and you will see the issue I am having.

Comment: Outside R, `sed 's/:./:\U&/' reptile_data.txt` would do the job.